# Drop down menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugin

I am making a dropdown menu in JavaScript for my website, and recently I decided I wanted to make it a plugin (as in, upload it on the web and make it compatible with other plugins). I am new to making plugins (and JavaScript) and I was wondering what you think of my code. My goal with the plugin is so that all the user needs to do is have the proper markup in their HTML along with some CSS, then include the script in their header, and it should make a functioning dropdown menu.

Here is the required markup:

```
<ul class="dropdown_container">
    <li class="super_tab"><a>Menu</a></li>

    <li><ul class="dropdown hidden">
        <li class="sub_tab"><a>Cater</a></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

I won't include the CSS because it is unimportant.

```
(function() {
    $(function Main() {

        this.setup = $(function() {
            self = this;
            this.cont_divs = this.getContDivs();
            this.cont_objs = this.defContObjects(this.cont_divs);

            this.mouseHovers();
        });

        this.mouseHovers = function() {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', '.super_tab',
                function() {
                    var parent = this.parentNode;
                    var cont = self.getContObj(parent, self.cont_objs);
                    cont.dropdown.show();
                }
            ).on('mouseleave', '.dropdown_container',
                function() {
                    var cont = self.getContObj(this, self.cont_objs);
                    cont.dropdown.hide();
                }
            ).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown_container',
                function() {
                    var cont = self.getContObj(this, self.cont_objs);
                    cont.setDimensions();
                }
            );
        }

        this.getContObj = function(other_div, cont_objs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cont_objs.length; i++) {
                if (other_div === cont_objs[i].div) {
                    return cont_objs[i];
                } 
            };
        }

        this.getContDivs = function() {
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_container");
            return divs;
        }

        this.defContObjects = function(sl_show_divs) {
            var cont_objs = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < sl_show_divs.length; i++) {
                var cont = new DropdownContainer(sl_show_divs[i]);
                cont_objs.push(cont);
            };

            return cont_objs;
        }

    });


    function DropdownContainer(div) {

        this.div = div;
        this.children = $(this.div).find('*');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            var child = this.children[i];

            if ($(child).hasClass("dropdown")) {
                this.dropdown = new Dropdown(child);
            } else if ($(child).hasClass("super_tab")) {
                this.super_tab = new SuperTab(child);
            }
        };

        this.setDimensions = function() {
            var drop_height = this.dropdown.getHeight();
            var super_tab_height = this.super_tab.getHeight();
            var new_height = super_tab_height + drop_height;

            if (this.dropdown.isVisible()) {
                this.setHeight(new_height);
            } else {
                this.setHeight(super_tab_height);
            }
        }

        this.setHeight = function(height) {
            this.div.style.height = height + 'px';
        }
    }


    function Dropdown(div) {

        this.div = div;
        this.children = this.div.childNodes;
        this.visible = false;

        this.show = function() {
            this.defVisibilityProps("block", "dropdown visible");
            this.visible = true;
        }

        this.hide = function() {
            this.defVisibilityProps("none", "dropdown hidden");
            this.visible = false;
        }

        this.getHeight = function() {
            return $(this.div).outerHeight();
        }

        this.isVisible = function() {
            return this.visible;
        }

        this.defVisibilityProps = function(display, class_names) {
            this.div.style.display = display; // Changing attribute "visibility" does not work as well. Use display.
            this.div.className = class_names; // Needed to tell what state the dropdown is currently in.
        }

    }

    function SuperTab(div) {

        this.div = div;
        this.children = this.div.childNodes;

        this.getHeight = function() {
            return $(this.div).outerHeight();
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you could shorten this up a bit

> ```
>     this.getContDivs = function() {
>         var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_container");
>         return divs;
>     }
> ```

and make it this instead:

```
this.getContDivs = function() {
    return document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_container");
}
```

You don't need to create a variable just to return the value, just return what you want to return here.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is badly structured. The dropdown menu items shouldn't be in a separate `li`. Something like this would be better:

```
<ul class="dropdown_container">
    <li class="super_tab">
        <a>Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown hidden">
            <li class="sub_tab"><a>Cater</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

- You use `$( ... )` (document ready) twice nested inside each other.
- The function `Main` is used anonymously, so it doesn't need a name.
- `Main` also isn't called as a constructor function or a method, so `this` inside it will reference `window` and all the functions you define in it (`setup`, `mouseHovers`, `getContObj`, all are written into the global namespace.
- The variable `self` is also in the global namespace.
- Any special reason you use `getElementsByClassName` instead of jQuery? It's not wrong, and most likely faster - if the browser supports it -, but it seems strange to mix jQuery and DOM queries.
- In a similar vein: jQuery provides `.each()` to loop over elements instead of `for` loops.
- I just realize there are more mixtures of jQuery and non-jQuery. (DOM's `.childNodes` instead of jQuery's `.children`,  `defVisibilityProps` instead of jQuery's `.toggle()`, etc.)
- `.find('*')` doesn't return all children, it returns all decedents. For the children use `.find('> *')` or just `.children()`. If you actually want the decedents, then rename the variable.

The is more, but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: Ok, what you said about the main function is totally correct and I fixed that. Though, from the html you suggest, it makes it seem as if the hidden dropdown is a part of the super tab, which it isn't. It is a part of the dropdown menu. The dropdown (the container for all the sub tabs) should be treated as a part of the dropdown menu, not a part of the super tab.  The dropdown menu (which I incorrectly named dropdown_container) is the whole thing, including the super tab and the sub tabs.

Comment: Also, about what you said about mixing jquery and javascript, this article says its totally normal to mix the two: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery. Though, your last point about the children variable is correct. I indeed wanted all the descendants, not the children of it.

Comment: Why do you think that the items should not be in a seperate li? @RoToRa

Comment: The HTML structure is just an example. To be honest I didn't quite understand your code, mainly because the class names `super_tab` and `sup_tab` are completely meaningless. The dropdown shouldn't be in a separate  `li` because the structure of a list means that each item is its separate "entity" on the same level, which a dropdown menu is not.

Comment: As I wrote, it's not wrong to mix jQuery and direct DOM access, but personally I find it really confusing and makes the code hard to read. Either you use jQuery or you don't. If you don't like jQuery (which I understand) because it's too complex/bloated/whatever, don't use it, or look for an alternative.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about the html. Let me try and explain the markup better. So there is one tab (what I called the super_tab) that is visible and once you hover over it, the other tabs (what I called sub_tabs) should become visible. What would be a better format for this? Also how can I improve the names? @RoToRa